# Phonegap geolocation not working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, mobile, geolocation

I try to make a (hybrid)webapp with Phonegap(3.7.0) and AngularJS that uses geolocation. My problem is that geolocation works in a browser, but not when I build the project in Phonegap and try to run it on a mobile device. When I remove the AngularJS controller in my Javascript the geolocator works like a charm on mobile devices. I tried to bootstrap AngularJS manually (for the DOM loading order), but that did not worked for me. Also the config file is correct at least I think.

Can anyone help me on this or giving me clues?

Thanks in advance

HTML

```
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0">

    <!-- Phonegap Javascript -->
    <script src="js/cordova/cordova.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- AngularJS Javascript -->
    <script src="js/angular/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/angular/angular-route.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Foundation for apps Javascript -->
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>

</head>

<body>  
      <div class="content-container" ng-app="mamyloeApp">
           <div ng-controller="UitjesDichtbijController" class="list-view-uitje">                        
               <ul ng-repeat="uitjes in uitjes.uitjes" class="list-item-uitje">
                   <li><a href='#'>
                        <div class="list-item-uitje-left">
                             <div class='uitje_list_image'>
                                   <img src="../library/photos/{{uitjes.list_image}}" alt='image'>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="list-item-uitje-right">
                                        <div class="naam-uitje">{{uitjes.overview}}</div>
                                        <div class="uitje-info">
                                            <div class="plaats-uitje">{{uitjes.city}}({{uitjes.distance | number:1}}km)</div>
                                            <div class="categorie-uitje">{{uitjes.category}}</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="naam-local">{{uitjes.firstname}}</div>
                                    </div>

                                </a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </div> 
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation/foundation.offcanvas.js"></script>

            <!-- Controller scripts -->
    <script src="js/load_list.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
```

Geolocator/AngularJS

```
var latitude = 0;
var longitude = 0;


var geo_initiate = false;

var App = angular.module('mamyloeApp', []);

App.controller('UitjesDichtbijController', function ($scope, $http) {

    function geolocation()
    {
        var options = {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 18000000};
        watchID = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);

        function onSuccess(position)
        {
            latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            longitude = position.coords.longitude;

            console.log("GPS is ready");
            console.log(latitude);
            console.log(longitude);

            $http.get("http://../Mamyloe_app/api/uitjes/" + latitude + "&" + longitude + "")
                    .success(function (response) {
                        $scope.uitjes = response;
                        console.log(response);
                    });

            geo_initiate = true;   

            if(geo_initiate === true){
                document.getElementById("content-container").style.visibility = "visible";
            }
        }
        function onError(error)
        {
            if (error.code = 1)
            {
                alert("Enable your GPS!");
            }
            console.log("GPS is NOT ready");
        }
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        geolocation();
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you have the following in your manifest code ? 



<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CORSE_LOCATION"/>

Comment: Yes I have and also added the feautures in the phonegap config file for Android and iOS. It's not a permission issue I think, the problem is AngularJS, when I remove this the geolocator works: 

var App = angular.module('mamyloeApp', []);

App.controller('UitjesDichtbijController', function ($scope, $http) { });

Comment: What do logs say ?   It should be telling something.

Comment: Channel not fired: onCordovaConnectionReady
Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady

Comment: Change `$(document).ready` to `$(document).on("deviceready")` for Cordova and put it outside of the controller declaration

Comment: When I put '$(document).on("deviceready")' outside the angular declaration, the geolocation function will be unused. When I put deviceready inside the declaration it also won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved, the access origin was the problem(access origin="*") in the config file and some capitals in the map structure, phonegap doesn't like that.